# SoundCloud API - populate database with user ID

Tags: javascript, database, api, soundcloud, populate

Here I have code that, using the SoundCloud API, will run functions to obtain the genre of a users likes and followings and then store these items in an object.

I would like to be able to populate the areas that require the user ID's automatically by inputting a user ID at the beginning and it automatically putting it in to create a database.

Now I am fairly new to coding so apologies if I haven't explained it very well and I don't even know if what I want to do is possible but any suggestions would be great!

Below is my failed attempt but it should give you an idea of what I am trying to do. I think the main problem occurs in the areas of where the SoundCloud API references are, e.g. `SC.get('/users/userIds[i]/favorites', function(favorites)`

```
var userIds = [9110252, 55829847, 145189041]

    for(u = 0; u < userIds.length; u++){

        var username = localStorage.getItem('useruserIds[i]username'); 
        var genre = localStorage.getItem('useruserIds[i]genrePref');
        var followings = localStorage.getItem('useruserIds[i]followings') 


        /************************* /USERS/FAVORITES.GENRE ***********************/
        // Iterate through user's likes to retrieve list of genres
        SC.get('/users/userIds[i]/favorites', function(favorites) {

            var userGenrePref = [];

            for(var i = 0; i < favorites.length; i++){

                userGenrePref.push(favorites[i].genre);

            }

            var userGenrePrefUp = userGenrePref.map(function(x) {return x.toLowerCase();});

            // Find the most common genre from the userGenrePrefUp array
            var frequency = {};  // array of frequency.
            var max = 0;  // holds the max frequency.


            for(var v in userGenrePrefUp) {
                frequency[userGenrePrefUp[v]]=(frequency[userGenrePrefUp[v]] || 0)+1; // increment frequency.
                if(frequency[userGenrePrefUp[v]] > max) { // is this frequency > max so far ?
                    max = frequency[userGenrePrefUp[v]];  // update max.
                    result = userGenrePrefUp[v];          // update result.
                }

            }

            var result;   // holds the max frequency element.

            localStorage.setItem('user'+userIds[i]+'genrePref',result);  

        });


        /******************** /USERS/FOLLOWINGS.USERNAME ********************/
        // Run through user's followers
        SC.get('/users/userIds[i]/followings',function(followings) {

        userFollowings = [];

            for(i = 0; i < followings.collection.length; i++) { 

            var bap = followingscollection[i].username  

                userFollowings.push(bap);                             

            }

            //console.log(userFollowings);
            localStorage.setItem('useruserIds[i]followings', JSON.stringify(userFollowings));                           

        });
    }



var users = {
    user : {username: username, genrePref: genre, followings: JSON.parse(followings)},
}

// Users array
var userProfile = [];

// Populate users array
for(var key in users) {
    userProfile.push(users[key]);
}

console.log(userProfile);
```